# I am trying to develop a second version of SkiFree using OllyDbg. How can I add a new enemy or obstacle without the source code?

Tags: debugging, game-hacking

I am a programmer and reverse engineer. I am interested in reverse engineering SkiFree since it is free to use.

However I have been wondering how to add a new enemy or obstacle since I do not have the original source code.

I tried contacting the Cheese (Chris Pirih) for the source code as he is the developer of the game. But no reply. Anyway, he gave me permission to toy around with the game rather than the source code.

Is there any way to add the code using OllyDbg? I been looking for a way.